# Test to check if button is disabled fails even though it is disabled

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, settimeout

I am new to testing in react. I have a button that plays an audiofile when pressed. The button is disabled for 4 seconds while the audio plays. I am trying to write a test to check if the button is in fact disabled during that time. I also want to write a test to check if the function is called with a 4 second delay.

This is my test code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, act, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Question from "./Question";

jest.mock('axios');
jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');

test('audio play should play once after click and be disabled', async () => {
   axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: {} });

await act(async () =>
  render(
    <Router>
      <Question fireAudio={() => <></>} />
    </Router>
  )
);
const button = screen.getByTestId('volume');

expect(button).toHaveProperty("disabled", false);
fireEvent.click(button);

expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(button).toBeDisabled();
expect(button).toHaveProperty("disabled", true);
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 4000);
});
```

This is the component it tests:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../Fill-In-Word/drainn_style'
import useStyles from "../Fill-In-Word/drainn_style";
import exerciseStyle from "../exerciseStyle";
import VolumeUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeUp';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';

const Question = ({ question, fireAudio, disabled }) => {
  const className = useStyles();
  const classesBase = exerciseStyle();
  const classes = { ...className, ...classesBase };

  return (
    <div className={classes.question}>
      <p>{question}</p>
      <IconButton
              onClick={fireAudio}
              disabled={disabled}
              data-testid="volume"
            >
              <VolumeUpIcon />
            </IconButton> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Question
```

This is the function that plays the audio and sets the delay:

```
  function fireAudio() {
    setDisabled(true);
    playAudio(forsaudio);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(false);
    }, 4000);
  }
```

The first test: `expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` passes, but the second test `expect(button).toBeDisabled();` fails saying it is not disabled even though it is when i run the code. I will add the error message as a photo.

[Error message for disabled test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A901l.png)

The third test fails with an error message i don't understand. Here is a photo of that:
[Error message for Timeout test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFpv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to simulate the 4-second timeout. Additionally, I would try using `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` instead of `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith`.

```js
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

// Exhaust `setTimeout` task queue
jest.runAllTimers();

expect(button).toBeDisabled();
expect(button).toHaveProperty("disabled", true);

// Try using `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith`
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, expect.any(Function), 4000);
```